# Making updates to google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

At present this is a hypothetical question and I haven't begun writing the code for this, mainly because I'm not sure if it is possible to achieve what I need to in Google Forms.

We have a employee contact form that is completed when they join the organisation, obviously people go through changes in life and either get a new mobile or change address, when this happens they change their contact details via a Google form, this adds a new row of data to the responses spreadsheet meaning that we have a duplicate entry for the same employee.

What I want to be able to do, is have the sheet look for duplicate data and overwrite the fields that have changed.  I am fairly confident that this is possible, however, I am struggling with the logic.

If it is possible?  Could you provide a hint as to how this might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to look for duplicates in a spreadsheet and delete them, however if you do it in the destination spreadsheet of a Google Form - the deleted duplicates will come back at every update.

### So you need a workaround:

1. Create a new spreadsheet (slave) that will be synchronized with the destination spreadsheet (master) on every form submit
2. The form data from each form submit will be checked for duplicates before being written into the slave
3. You need a unique identifier, e.g. employee number
4. You can check either an entry with this identifier already exists in the slave, e.g. with [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
5. If the identifier does not exist yet - append the new data to the last row of the slave
6. If the identifier exists already - find the row containing it and overwrite it with new data